# How to store data from website to parse.com And how to to fetch data of it in my application

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I want to use the parse database for developing web app, since data will upload from the desktop PC and retreival of the same will be done in parse mobile application.

Is it possible to use the parse database for website backend ?

Since I want to use same parse database for application and desktop version.

Can anyone please help me, by providing some idea how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Is it possible to use the parse database for website backend ?
```

YES, it is possible: [.NET Guide](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide), [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest)

```
Since I want to use same parse database for application and desktop version.
```

YES, you can use same database for application and desktop version.

---

for store data using ANDROID create object like:

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

above code is create table in parse.com(**database is automatically created when you store data using object.**) check dashboard: like below image

[image]

for fetch data try this way:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

same way you can use for WEB Application as well Desktop application ([REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest))

---

**for create table User i have to create object like:**

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("User");
    gameScore.put("First Name", "dhaval");
    gameScore.put("Last Name", "Sodha");
    gameScore.put("Email", "xyz@gmail.com");
    gameScore.put("Phone", "9876543210");
    gameScore.put("Address", "xyz");
    gameScore.put("City", "ahmedabad");
    gameScore.put("Country", "India");
    gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

above Object ll create table with fields(**ID ,First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone, Address, City, ... time, created...etc** )

---

**EDITED:**

---

get data like (`SELECT * FROM USER WHERE CITY = 'AHMEDABAD' and COUNTRY = 'INDIA'`)

```
           ParseQuery lotsOfWins = new ParseQuery("User");
            lotsOfWins.whereEqualTo("city", "Ahmedabad");

            ParseQuery fewWins = new ParseQuery("User");
            fewWins.whereEqualTo("country", "India");

            List<ParseQuery> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery>();
            queries.add(lotsOfWins);
            queries.add(fewWins);

            ParseQuery mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
            mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
                    // HERE SIZE is 0 then 'No Data Found!'
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

---

Here: `public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e)` you get result in object

`List<ParseObject>`: is list of object return by query.

`ParseException`: is Exception if occur..

So, `scoreList.size()` give you Total size of all Object return by Query.

How Fetch data:

```
String username = scoreList.getString("username");
```

---

**How Save File: (Whatever MIME type like png,jpg,doc,txt....etc)its works for all**

Upload File using Below code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                USERIMAGE.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                String UsetPhoto = "user"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"image";
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile(UsetPhoto, byteArray);

                ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("UserDetails");
                gameScore.put("userName", "" + userName.getText().toString());
                gameScore.put("userPhoto", "" + file);
                gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

**retrive file from parse API using above object:**

```
ParseFile applicantResume = (ParseFile)gameScore.get("userPhoto");
            applicantResume.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
              public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                  // data has the bytes for the resume
                } else {
                  // something went wrong
                }
              }
            });
```

Here you get: `public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e)`

`byte[]` : `byte[]` of file(whatever file type - if you have uploaded png then save that byte as png).

`ParseException` : is Exception if occur..

Comment: what i want is that i want to store data from website.

Comment: Thanks it helps me. Can you tell me one another thing like to do two parse query at the same time like whose "city" is "ahmedabad" and "country" is "India" iwant show their name otherwise it will show "not found" msg?

Comment: // HERE SIZE is 0 then 'No Data Found!'  what  is "size" here? can you explain that a bit?

Comment: thanks a lot it really helps me. Just one last thing can you help me? Like can i add a video, audio file into parse database if yes how to fetch it from android application and display it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for assist me and spending a lot more time to tech me all these. I will let you know later if I need any extra assistance from you. Thank you.

Comment: How can I update my previously created score because each time `ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("User");` creating a new row.
I want to update previous row. Thanks.