# How to map sqlite and parse mobile object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse mobile sdk with android. I want to create login and store the data in sqlite DB. I am new to this. Can somebody give a example to how to do it?

Does ParseUser maps by itself?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476240/how-to-store-data-from-website-to-parse-com-and-how-to-to-fetch-data-of-it-in-my/16476327#16476327