# Saving Bitmap image to parseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

how can i save my Bitmap image to the parseObject?
this is my code

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getBundleExtra("extras");
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail)
```

The parseObject code

```
ParseObject movie = new ParseObject("movies");
                movies.put("title", title.getText().toString());
                movies.put("description", description.getText().toString());
                movies.saveInBackground();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",   
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

How can i save the Bitmap image into the ParseObject "movie" ?

Comment: Send is in the form of Base64.

Comment: Chek answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16476327

Answer (score 0):

You can use ParseFile to save a bitmap on parse

basically you need to do something like this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedScaledMealImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);// can use something 70 in case u want to compress the image 

        byte[] scaledData = bos.toByteArray();

        // Save the scaled image to Parse
        photoFile = new ParseFile("image_to_be_saved.jpg", scaledData);
        photoFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Error saving: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    //filed saved successfully :)
                }
            }
        });
```

you can then easily put the ParseFile inside any ParseObject
like this

```
ParseObject po = new ParseObject("anyObject");
po.put("file",parseFileObj);
```

Hope this helps